# django rest framework, how to prefetch_related with a single object

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-orm

for some reason，I pass an instance(not queryset) to ModelSerializer. but I want to do prefetch_related with this instance.

```
# instance is a Workout object
instance = queryset.order_by('?').first()
# I want to do something like: instance.prefetch_related('exercises') to avoid N+1 problem
workout = WorkoutModelSerializer(instance)
return Response(workout.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

```
# custom manytomany through model
class WorkoutExercises(models.Model):
    workout = models.ForeignKey(Workout, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rule = models.ForeignKey(Rule, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

# ModelSerializer
class WorkoutModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    calorie = SerializerMethodField(help_text='calorie')
    def get_calorie(self, obj):
        calorie = 0
        for exercise in obj.exercises.defer('calorie'):
            calorie += exercise.calorie
        return calorie

    exercise_group = SerializerMethodField()
    def get_exercise_group(self, obj):
        for exercise in obj.exercises.all():
           relation = obj.workoutexercises_set.filter(exercise=exercise).first()
           group_name = relation.rule.group_name 
           # do something with group_name and other rule property ...
```

I use debug_toolbar, It show N+1 problem(maybe I am wrong)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey Tony, are you calling this core in a loop? Otherwise, there should not be a N+1 problem, since the Django ORM will fetch related exercises only once anyway.

Comment: @Ilya Khrustalev, I'm not sure, maybe SerializerMethodField will call this in a loop?

Comment: Tony, looking into your SerlizerMethod I noticed that you're using `.defer('calorie')` which suppose to fetch the data WITHOUT the selected field. I think you probably want to call `.only` or even omit both. Probably this cause N+1 problem.

Comment: Tony, sorry to give you an advice you didn't ask for, but I think it could be useful. You can simplify your code and get rid of SerializerMethod by executing Sum on database level instead of doing it yourself in python: `workout = queryset.annotate(calorie=Sum(F('exercises__calorie')).order_by('?').first()` - this adds a `calorie` field on the Result set which will be the sum of calories of all exercieses. Don't forget to import F and Sum: `from django.db.models import F, Sum`

Comment: @Ilya Khrustalev, You are right, it is caused by defer.
If you could help me take a look at get_exercise_group also, i will be very appreciated.
You can write an answer. I think it will be a case of how to use Django ORM correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete code from our comments including your last ask:

```py
instance = (
    queryset.order_by('?')
        .annotate(calorie=Sum(F('exercises__calorie'))  # Get total calories by run `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` and store the result in a new `calorie` field.
        .prefetch_related(
            'workoutexercises_set__rule',               # Prefeth exercises relations, rule, and exercse.
            'workoutexercises_set__exercise',
        )  
)

# Later in your serializer

class WorkoutModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    calorie = serializers.IntegerField(help_text='calorie')  # Will be taken from new `calorie` aggregated field

    exercise_group = SerializerMethodField()
    def get_exercise_group(self, obj):
        for relation in obj.workoutexercises_set.all():      # Relations will be prefetched and the call doesn't lead to N+1.
            exercise = relation.exercise                     # As well as related rule and exercise
            rule = relation.rule
            group_name = relation.rule.group_name 
            # do something with group_name and other rule property ...
```

Basically, the idea is to delegate compution to the Database where possible and prefetch models you're going to use later in your code.

One pitfall easy to get into is calling anything beside `.all()` on prefetched models, since it leads to an extra call to executed.

I hope it helps, let me know if there is any unclarity.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
instance = queryset.order_by('?').prefetch_related('exercises').first()
```

should do the trick.

Comment: You need to override the `get_queryset` method in your viewset and include the prefetch_related  there. This will solve your issue